# ThreeJS Get OrbitControls View Result and Use As Default Position

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I use OrbitControls in ThreeJS the user will be able to move about the camera. The user is also able to refresh the model however upon reload the camera will move back to the default position.

I've already tried using this:

```
camera.position.x = lastPosX
...
...
camera.rotation.x = lastRotX
...
...
```

However the result is not correct and it doesn't look like the view I had before (somehow it looks inverted and just overall the wrong way around).

What am I missing? How can I replicate the exact view the user has when he moves the camera using the OrbitControls after refreshing the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to do a `camera.position.set(x,y,z)` ?
It may not matter but maybe setting them all once might give it the correct orientation

Comment: I've read somewhere that using .set works different to the method I showed above.. might give it a shot. Does this also work for rotation e.g. `camera.rotation.set()` ?

Comment: I'll try this out as soon as possible and if it works, I'll mark this answer as accepted.. thanks!

Comment: Finally got around trying it. Works perfectly fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the camera coordinates to a global variable in the update function like every 2 secs and when they refresh, load the latest coordinates.